# What is this kind of widget called? Connector? Wire?

Tags: user-interface, widget

*Click on one point on a widget and drag it to another point on another widget, and a connection (wire, cable, line) is made between the two.*

I'm looking for a (open source) web toolkit that has this type of widget, but I don't even know what it is called. So it's a bit difficult to find. Examples would be nice.

Comment: @ghoti, Any. I just want to know the name of it, if there is any, so I can look at the options, if any.

Comment: I would call them "connecting lines".  I've seen implementations in Flash and JavaScript, and the name for each was based on the application it was used in.  I'm not aware of a standard library for implementing this functionality, let alone a "widget".

Comment: MS has them in the SQL Server Management Studio and in lots of other products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this project: https://github.com/sporritt/jsPlumb.
Here's the demo in action: http://jsplumb.org/jquery/demo.html

Comment: Very nice! I might even be able to use this.

Answer (score 0):

we have done something like this in Flash ActionScript with getting the initial co-ordinates of the items and the co-ordinates of of the destination position.

Further we called DrawLine function using these for points and it was very eay task.

For opensource i am not sure but it should be very easy in my opinion.

Comment: Nice, but what is such a control/widget normally called?

Comment: drag drop connector maybe  see the link and an example of it here

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/drag-and-drop/drag-drop-create-line-connection.aspx